# psql ERROR: relation already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I'm writing a rails project using postgres and there is some data in the server. And I want dump the data from the remote end to the local, so I write script to do it, but some errors come out.

This's the dump script:

```
run "PGPASSWORD='#{remote_settings['password']}' 
pg_dump -U #{remote_settings["username"]} #{"-h '#{remote_settings["host"]}'" 
if remote_settings["host"]} 
'#{remote_settings["database"]}' > #{remote_sql_file_path}"
```

There's some codes to transport..

```
Transport codes
```

And this's the restore script:

```
run_locally "PGPASSWORD='#{local_settings['password']}' psql -U 
#{local_settings["username"]} -d #{local_settings["database"]} 
-f #{local_sql_file_path}"
```

I get the data file successfully, but when there're some **ERRORs* when **restore script** is run:

```
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:46: ERROR:  relation        "refinery_images" already exists
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:49: ERROR:  role "ib5k" does not exist
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:60: ERROR:  relation "refinery_images_id_seq" already exists
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:63: ERROR:  role "ib5k" does not exist
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:83: ERROR:  relation "refinery_page_part_translations" already exists
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:86: ERROR:  role "ib5k" does not exist
...
sql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:525: ERROR:  duplicate key  value violates unique constraint "refinery_images_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY refinery_images, line 2: ""
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:547: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "refinery_page_part_translations_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY refinery_page_part_translations, line 8: ""
psql:tmp/production-ib5k_production-2013-02-21_18:42:09.sql:569: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "refinery_page_parts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY refinery_page_parts, line 8: ""
...
```

And the database in local will not be updated.
I want to know how to solve it? Adding some arguments? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `-c` or `--clean` argument to [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html). That argument will drop existing database objects before running the commands to create them.

An alternative is to drop those objects yourself before restoring. (Probably using `drop schema` or `drop database`.)

Use with caution.

Comment: What does this option do in `pg_dump`? I would expect the option to be passed to `pg_restore` instead.

Comment: @JohnEye: "Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless --if-exists is also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

This option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore."
 [Current docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)